# Issues with checkbox for menu and javascript

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I'm learning web development... And i'm stuck.

i have a checkbox menu, when its checked i have to hide the menu. by default for a large screen the menu is displayed and the checkbox is unchecked and by default when the screen is under 930px the checkbox have to be checked... thats my problem
I don't know how to setup that: my code is this

```
    var largeur = window.innerWidth;
    var checkbox = document.querySelector('input[name=menuOn]');

    if(largeur< 930) {
        checkbox.checked;
        checkbox.addEventListener('change',function(){
            if(this.checked) {
                document.getElementById('testHide').style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById('altMenu').style.display = "unset";
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById('testHide').style.display = "unset";
                document.getElementById('altMenu').style.display = "none";
            }

        })}
```

For the script

my html is this

```
 <div class="switchContainer">
     <input type="checkbox" class="headerSwitch" name="menuOn">
<p id="altMenu" class="altMenu">Menu</p> 
 </div>
```

I don't know where is the probleme and if i am on the good way to do that.
Sorry for my english.

Paul

Comment: Looking into the code, You are calculating the width only once (on page load i guess), You need to do it on `$( window ).resize(function() {// Your code});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do it on page load as well as on resize of the window.

Please check below example -

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
   myFunction();
});

$(window).on("load resize",function(e){
  myFunction();
});


function myFunction(){
  var largeur = window.innerWidth;
  var checkbox = document.querySelector('input[name=menuOn]');
  if(largeur< 930) {
    checkbox.checked;
    checkbox.addEventListener('change',function(){
      if(this.checked) {
          document.getElementById('testHide').style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById('altMenu').style.display = "unset";
      }
      else {
          document.getElementById('testHide').style.display = "unset";
          document.getElementById('altMenu').style.display = "none";
      }
    })
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="switchContainer">
     <input type="checkbox" class="headerSwitch" name="menuOn">
     <p id="altMenu" class="altMenu">Menu</p> 
     <div id="testHide">testHide</div>
 </div>
```

Note - This snippet will not work in it. But on your page, it will work.